# Component not rendering in in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react component is not rendering and i have no bugs.
The issue is that if i change the **isLoggedIn state** to "true", my **HeroSlide** will not render

if **isLoggedin = false** then: [image]

if **isLoggedIn = true** then: [image]

Here is my code

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BigMovieTile from "../MoviesTile/BigMovieTile";
import "./HeroSlider.css";
import tmdbAPI, { type, movieType, tvType } from "../../config/api";
import apiConfig from "../../config/apiconfg";

const HeroSlider = () => {
  const [animateIn, setAnimateIn] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [heroMovies, setHeroMovie] = useState([]);
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState(
    "./images/movie-poster-collage.jpg"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMovies = async () => {
      const params = { page: 1 };
      try {
        const response = await tmdbAPI.getMoviesList(movieType.popular, {
          params,
        });
        setHeroMovie(response.data.results.slice(0, 4));
        // console.log(heroMovies);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimateIn(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <div id="hero-slider-bg">
        <img src={placeholder} className="hero-slider-img" />
        <div className="hero-overlay">
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            heroMovies.map((movie) => {
              // {({ isActive }) =>
              //   setPlaceholder(
              //     apiConfig.originalImage(
              //       movie.backdrop_path
              //         ? movie.backdrop_path
              //         : movie.poster_path
              //     )
              //   )
              // }
              console.log(movie.title);
              {
                try {
                  <>
                    <HeroSlide
                      data={movie}
                      backgroundImage={placeholder}
                      animateIn={animateIn}
                    />
                    <h1>Working</h1>
                  </>;
                } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              }
            })
          ) : (
            <div id="hero-slider-welcome">
              <div className="hero-welcome-side">
                <div className="hero-side-details" id="hero-welcome-details">
                  <h1 className={` ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}>
                    Unlimited Movies and Tv series
                  </h1>
                  <h3 className={`sub-text ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}>
                    Welcome to the world of Entertainment. Where you can get all
                    Movies and Tv series for free
                    <br />
                    Download is available in all formats
                    <br />
                    Proceed to sign in if you have an account, else sign up to
                    create a new account
                  </h3>
                  <div
                    id="hero-welcome-buttons"
                    className={`hero-buttons ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}
                  >
                    <button className="btn">
                      <h4>Sign up</h4>
                    </button>
                    <button className="relative-btn">
                      <h4>Sign in</h4>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="hero-welcome-side">
                <BigMovieTile
                  size={"small"}
                  isActive={animateIn ? "active" : ""}
                />
                <BigMovieTile isActive={animateIn ? "active" : ""} />
                <BigMovieTile
                  size={"small"}
                  isActive={animateIn ? "active" : ""}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

This is my hero slide

```
const HeroSlide = ({ data, backgroundImage, animateIn }) => {
  return (
    <div id="hero-slider-bg">
      <img src={backgroundImage} className="hero-slider-img" />
      <div className="hero-overlay">
        <div id="hero-slider-main">
          <div id="hero-main-poster">
            <BigMovieTile
              isActive={animateIn ? "active" : ""}
              size={"large"}
              imageUrl={
                movie.poster_path ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="hero-main-side">
            <div id="hero-main-details" className="hero-side-details">
              <h1 className={` ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}>Movie title</h1>
              <h3 className={`sub-text ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}>
                Movie overview
                <br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Aspernatur, consequuntur! Vel, expedita excepturi velit sint
                corrupti ratione facilis aperiam quos magnam omnis numquam fuga,
                quibusdam dolore laudantium sunt voluptate minus similique id
                perspiciatis dolores cumque delectus. Aspernatur porro facilis
                nisi quos, provident, adipisci dolor placeat excepturi
                temporibus asperiores nihil voluptatum.
              </h3>
              <div className={`hero-buttons ${animateIn ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <button className="btn">
                  <h4>Watch now</h4>
                </button>
                <button className="relative-btn">
                  <h4>Watch trailer</h4>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeroSlider;
```

How can i solve this issue, am not a pro developer, just learnt ReactJs few weeks ago
Please help

Comment: why you add try catch in above <HeroSlide/> ?

Comment: You've a typo in your code, `heroMovies.map` is missing returning JSX to render. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use "return" inside the map function try block:

```
try {
  return (
    <>
      <HeroSlide
        data={movie}
        backgroundImage={placeholder}
        animateIn={animateIn}
      />
      <h1>Working</h1>
    </>
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Also, it is not necessary to use try/catch block inside a JSX block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the way you are trying to render the HeroSlide.

You can try changing your code with this :

```
 {isLoggedIn ? (
  heroMovies.map((movie) => (
    <React.Fragment key={movie.id}>
      <HeroSlide
        data={movie}
        backgroundImage={
          apiConfig.originalImage(
            movie.backdrop_path ? movie.backdrop_path : movie.poster_path
          )
        }
        animateIn={animateIn}
      />
      <h1>Working</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
) : (
  // ... (the existing code for the "else" block)
)}
```